# SQL Server constraints on foreign keys

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, sql-server-2008, ssms

I have an ItemComments table that has one column with a foreign key constraint linking back to an item entry in a second table.  I see this as a one-to-many relationship as each item in the second table can have many comments, but no two items can be associated with the same comment entry in the ItemComments table, so a many-to-many relationship does not apply.

PROBLEM:

I want to define a constraint on this column that will prevent the foreign key value from being updated, i.e. I want to prevent someone from accidentally changing the item ID that a specific ItemComment entry is associated with.  I'm not very familiar with the expression formatting of constraint check and was curious what the syntax would be for such an action.  Or is there another more straightforward way of accomplishing this?  Thanks for the help.

UPDATE

Is it better to implement a cross-reference table as you would in a many-to-many relationship to enforce referential integrity in this way?  Or is that adding more overhead than is necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use a trigger.  Something like:

```
create trigger dml_PreventUpdate
on YourTable
after update
as
    if UPDATE(ItemId)
    rollback
```

There's two types of Data Manipulation Language (DML) triggers.  There's an `INSTEAD OF` and then an `AFTER/FOR` trigger (`AFTER` and `FOR` function the same way).  An `INSTEAD OF` trigger, as the name implies, executes prior to the transaction taking place.  An `AFTER` trigger, again as the name implies, executes after the triggered action.

Basically all this trigger is doing is testing to see if the `ItemId` column is updated from the `UPDATE` statement run against the table, `YourTable`.  This trigger will fire every time there is an `UPDATE` against `YourTable`, but it will only `ROLLBACK` the transaction if `ItemId` is an updated field.

Comment: Hi Shark, I'll admit I'm not familiar with using triggers, but this sounds like an option.  I'll read more on the subject.

Comment: @kingrichard2005 I have edited my post and added a brief explanation on triggers and what exactly is happening.

Comment: I see, sounds like triggers are the way to go.  I will accept your answer.  Thanks Shark.

Comment: You might want to `raiserror` in addition to doing the rollback.